# Inheritance Initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

```
Class Contact():
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.obj1 = obj1
        self.obj2 = obj2

Class Phonebook():
    def __init__(self):
        # leave this empty for now

    def add(self, contact):
        contact = Contact()

contact1 = Contact('Name', '000')
a = Phonebook()
a.add(contact1)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there another way to init?
I am trying to make a contact in a class and then after I create it, I add it to the Phonebook.

Comment: This is composition, not inheritance

Comment: Hard to say what you're doing wrong since you don't say what you expect to happen or what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add contacts into a phone book, you need some way to store them, so your constructor cannot be empty. It needs a list

```
class Phonebook():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [] 

    def add(self, contact):
        self.items.append(contact)
```

You've already made a Contact object, so you don't need to make another one in the add function

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with this code.

---

First, as pointed out by Azat Ibrakov, `Class` is not a valid keyword; you want `class`.

While we're at it, while `class Contact():` *is* valid, there's really no reason for the empty parentheses.

So:

```
class Contact:
```

---

Next, `Contact.__init__` tries to use variables named `obj1` and `obj2` that don't exist, which will fail with a `NameError`.

It's also taking parameters named `name` and `phone` but never using them. Presumably those are the values you wanted to store.

Also, while it isn't an error, it's not very useful to store names and phone numbers in attributes named `obj1` and `obj2`; give them meaningful attribute names.

So:

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
```

---

Next, `Phonebook.add` tries to create a new `Contact`, but doesn't pass it arguments for `name` and `phone`, so that will fail with a `TypeError`.

But what arguments should you pass? You don't have a name, or a phone number.

You *do* have a `contact` parameter. You're trying to throw that value away and replace it with a brand-new `Contact` object, but why would you want to do that? Surely you want to use the one that was passed in.

So, to fix `Phonebook.add`… there's really nothing for it to do at all:

```
class Phonebook:
    def __init__(self):
        # leave this empty for now

    def add(self, contact):
        # leave this empty too
```

---

But your goal was to add contacts to a phone book. That means you have to store those contacts somewhere.

A phone book is like a dictionary, where you can look up contact info by name. So, let's use a `dict`. This should be an attribute of a `Phonebook` object, which means we want to create it in `__init__`, so we can use it in other methods like `add` later:

```
class Phonebook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contacts = {}

    def add(self, contact):
        self.contacts[contact.name] = contact
```